# How to map all keys of a nested dictionary to a dataframe using an individual column per key in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am new to python and I am trying to achieve the following.

I have this dictionary:

```
cust_DB = {'cust_ID': {'NAME': 'name', 'ADDRESS': 'address', 'PHONES': {'HOME_PHONE': 'home#', 'WORK_PHONE': 'work#', 'MOBILE_PHONE': 'mobile#'}, 'EMAILS': {'HOME_EMAIL': 'email@home', 'WORK_EMAIL': 'email@work'}
```

I would like to transform and put this dictionary into a pandas dataframe df with the following columns df and corresponding records:

```
'ID'|'NAME'|'ADDRESS'|'HOME_PHONE'|'WORK_PHONE'|'MOBILE_PHONE'|'HOME_EMAIL'|'WORK_EMAIL'
```

If I use pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(), the nested phone numbers and emails are grouped in one column each. Is there a quick way to populate that dataframe?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this custom `flatten` function:

```
def flatten(d):
    ret = dict()
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            sub = flatten(v)
            for kk, vv in sub.items():
                ret[kk] = vv
        else: ret[k] = v
    return ret

out = pd.DataFrame({k:flatten(v) for k, v in cust_DB.items()})
out = out.T.rename_axis('ID').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    ID       ADDRESS    HOME_EMAIL    HOME_PHONE    MOBILE_PHONE    NAME    WORK_EMAIL    WORK_PHONE
--  -------  ---------  ------------  ------------  --------------  ------  ------------  ------------
 0  cust_ID  address    email@home    home#         mobile#         name    email@work    work#
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer below is very long.

However, I am a believer in the following old adage:

> If you give a man a fish, he will eat for a day.
> If you teach a man to fish, he will eat for a lifetime.

You have a dictionary of dictionaries.
I encourage you to visualize the nested dictionary as a tree:

[image: TREE DIAGRAM]

A "***leaf*** " is simply a ***node*** (nodes are circle/dot) in a tree which does not have any children. "Leaves" are like human bachelors, or spinsters: they have no kids.

It sounds like you want one of the following two things. I am not sure which....

- you want to use ***only*** the leaves of the tree as column headers of a table.
- you want extract parents of leaf nodes in the tree. The parents of leaves will become column headers for a table

This is often referred to as "flattening" the tree.

```
cust_DB = {'cust_ID': {'NAME': 'name', 'ADDRESS': 'address', 'PHONES': {'HOME_PHONE': 'home#', 'WORK_PHONE': 'work#', 'MOBILE_PHONE': 'mobile#'}, 'EMAILS': {'HOME_EMAIL': 'email@home', 'WORK_EMAIL': 'email@work'}}}

def flatten(parent):
    """
    [* crickets chirping for lack of code-comments* ]
    """
    if not hasattr(parent, '__iter__'):
        return parent
    leaves = list()
    root_type = type(parent)
    for child_key in iter(parent):
        child = parent[child_key]
        if type(child) == type(parent):
            subleaves = flatten(child)
            leaves.extend(subleaves)
        else:
            leaves.append(child)
    return leaves

leaves = flatten(cust_DB)

result = "\n".join(map(str, iter(leaves)))
print(result)
```

I see that:

- The leaves of your tree might be actual data (actual phone numbers)
- the parents of the leaf nodes are column headers of the table ("home phone," "work phone," etc...)

I recommend the following solution:

1. Google "python flatten dictionary tree." The flatten function I give above works, but is ugly. Some other people have written more elegant flatten functions.
2. Modify someone's `flatten` function to get parents of leaf nodes instead of leaves.

If you have never learned about depth-first-search or breadth-first-search, I recommend watching a YouTube video on those topics.

#### WARNING/CAUTION:

There is one issue which arises:

iterators of python lists return values, not key.
iterators of python dictionaries return keys, not values.

Python is what I like to call a "*two steps forward, one step back*" language. That is, Python is better than old Languages ( like **C**) in some ways, and Python is worse in other ways.

If Python were well-designed, all built-in containers (`list`, `dict`, etc...) would distinguish between key-iterators and value-iterators.

```
lyst = ["Spam", "Toast", "Eggs"]
# The keys (inputs) of lyst  are:
#    0, 1, 2
# The values (outputs) of `lyst` are:
#     Spam", "Toast", and "Eggs"

dyct = {0: "Spam", 1:"Toast", 2:"Eggs"}
# The keys (inputs) of dyct  are:
#    0, 1, 2
# The values (outputs) of `dyct` are:
#     Spam", "Toast", and "Eggs"

print("LIST STUFF IS BELOW")
for element in lyst:
    print(element)

print(end = "\n")

print("DICT STUFF IS BELOW")
for element in dyct:
    print(element)
```

You would think the output would be the same for both lists and dictionaries, but the output is different.

```
LIST STUFF IS BELOW
Spam
Toast
Eggs
    
DICT STUFF IS BELOW
0
1
2
```

You have to be very carful, and know ahead of time, whether the container is a dictionary or a list. Otherwise, your for-loops will loop over indices/keys (inputs) instead of values (outputs).

```
#####################################
# BEGIN CODE FOR LISTS
#####################################
for child in parent:
    flatten(child)     # FOR LISTS
#####################################
# END OF CODE FOR LISTS
#---------------------------
# BEGIN CODE FOR DICTIONARIES
#####################################
for child_key in parent:
    child = parent[child_key]  # FOR DICTIONARIES
    flatten(child)
#####################################
# END OF CODE FOR DICTIONARIES
#####################################
```